# Created a web service using Flask. But getting the output in HTML tags

Tags: python, flask

Result image
[image]

My aim is to display 'Hello *inputname*'

web.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>',methods=['GET'])
def index(name):
    return jsonify({'out' : "Hello " + str(name)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the issue here, could you explain bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the output in 'HTML tags', you're getting a JSON string.

This code:

```
jsonify({'out': 'Hello'})
```

creates a string `"{'out': 'Hello'}"` within a Flask `Response` object.

To get your desired result you need:

```
return "Hello "+str(name)
```